# Is it possible to copy a file from a directory into a subdirectory in all other directories via a cmd/batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, cmd

So the scenario is this...

I have my folder structure

```
 - C:\
     - DirectoryA 
         - SubdirA
             - File.xml     
     - DirectoryB    
         - SubdirB     
     - DirectoryC
         - SubdirC
     .
     .
     .
```

My question is,
Is there a way to copy the file from SubdirA into ALL subdirectories of all other directories, in a batch/cmd file, without a massive list of copy statements?

Comment: Just a note: I hope your target directories have names that follow a specific pattern or the root for the targets is something different than actually the system drive's root directory. Otherwise you risk confusing system directories (or any other irrelevant ones) with the targets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excuse me, there are a couple unclear points about this question.

At first, I thought you want to "copy the file from SubdirA into ALL subdirectories of all other directories" *at the same level where the file is*, that is, if SubdirB and/or SubdirC would have subdirectories beneath, the file will NOT be copied to them; just to SubdirB and SubdirC. If a DirectoryD would exist that have NOT another subdirectory beneath, the file will NOT be copied to it. The Batch file below do such process:

```
@echo off
set "theFile=C:\DirectoryA\SubdirA\File.xml"

for /F "tokens=2 delims=\" %%a in ("%theFile%") do set "originDir=%%a"
cd \
for /d %%a in (*) do (
   if not "%%a" == "%originDir%" (
      pushd %%a
      for /d %%b in (*) do (
         copy "%theFile%" "\%%a\%%b"
      )
      popd
   )
)
```

However, you said later: "The directories will all be at the same level, ie directly below C:" that contradicts your own example! The directories in the example are two levels down.

Please note that this point (the level of the target directories) is crucial to correctly write a Batch file (in case the file above does not solve your problem).

Comment: `cd /d drive:\ ` might be a better choice since you cannot be sure if the active dir is on the same drive as the target root dir.

Comment: Sorry, I realise that my question may have been poorly worded. Your first interpretation is actually what it is I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually writing the batch file myself, you'd want to use "for /d" which will iterate over directories, and put that into a loop that can recursively call itself.